# ViewModel property binding to null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this ViewModel

```
 public class MyViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer{ get; set; }
    public Account Account{ get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate{ get; set; }
}
```

This View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Final", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer)....

        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Customer.FirstName) //This displays the name ok
```

And this is my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Final(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Customer.... //This is null
```

The problem is, I don´t have to edit the properties, only show them and then save to the database, that´s why I use HiddenFor, but the properties Customer and Account bind to null.
What is the problem? Maybe the HiddenFor?

PS: I have the GET method in which I perform the appropriate return View(viewModel)

This is where I pass the ViewModel

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Final()
    {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {

           //set the properties, etc
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you passing the model from

Comment: The model for the View is @model ...MyViewModel

Comment: Seems like you don't want to request database twice. But keeping only ID of customer inside Hidden would be much easier. Or you can keep the Customer object inside `TempData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customer is a complex object, so you will need each property of Customer as a hidden field.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.FirstName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.LastName)
```

Alternatively, you can store the entire `MyViewModel` in `TempData` which uses Session State under the hood.

Comment: That´s what did it, Thanks!